# Change ControlTemplate from a Trigger in .xaml file

Tags: wpf, controltemplate, datatrigger

I have few control templates defined with CRK key and they are applied through a trigger

```
<ControlTemplate
    x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=SubmenuItemTemplateKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}}"
    TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
....
</ControlTemplate>
```

And these templates are applied through a trigger

```
 <Style x:Key="{x:Static keys:Menu.DefaultItemContainerStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template"
            Value="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=SubmenuItemTemplateKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}}}" />
    <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="Role" Value="TopLevelHeader">
        <Setter Property="Template"
                Value="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=TopLevelHeaderTemplateKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}}}" />
      </Trigger>
      ...
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
```

This works, but I don't want control templates be default across the app, and instead want to control through them through a key.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="SubmenuItemTemplateKey" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
    ...
</ControlTemplate>
```

For some reason, trigger cannot locate the ControlTemplates when referenced through key directly

```
 <Style x:Key="{x:Static keys:Menu.DefaultItemContainerStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template" 
            Value="{DynamicResource SubmenuItemTemplateKey}" />
    <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="Role" Value="TopLevelHeader">
        <Setter Property="Template"
                Value="{DynamicResource TopLevelHeaderTemplateKey}" />
      </Trigger>
      ...
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
```